# Why is my game working in all browsers but FF?

Tags: jquery, firefox, cross-browser

In Chrome, this game works just fine. But in Firefox - it does not. **I'm stuck... and I really don't know what to do.**

I'm new to programming in general (and jQuery) so sorry if the code looks a bit messy.

Again, this code works just fine in Chrome. But not in Firefox. Why is that? **It just keeps giving me 1 point for clicking happiness every time. But only in Firefox.**

Live link to site in question: http://facetest.info

Link to JS: http://facetest.info/stuff.js

Answer (score 0):

If you open you console you will see

> ReferenceError: `trolli` is not defined
>   `setTimeout(trolli,3000);`

So define them *before* calling them..